# autodesk-forge, 2-legged Authentication (OAuth): oauth

Tags: authentication, oauth, autodesk-forge

Not sure what I did wrong, for 2 legged authentication. I am using cygwin terminal for curl.
Cullback URL is 
http://localhost:3000/api/forge/callback/oauth

Please see the code below and let me know what is wrong. Not sure what is wrong.
 jq version is 1.6, curl 7.64.1 
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)

To me it looks like, HTTP version is the reason of the error.I am very new for forge. So give me some idea, about what is wrong here.

```
 $ curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'client_id=qWSjFdCYTfhWsLZCSsLcSZCrDY2GsVSq' -d 'client_secret=PChX1GbaPFG42hQi' -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' -d 'scope=data:all'
```

output error report as below:

```
    * STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x8000770d8; line 1356 (connection #-5000)
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITRESOLVE handle 0x8000770d8; line 1397 (connection #0)
*   Trying 34.212.2.95:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* STATE: WAITRESOLVE => WAITCONNECT handle 0x8000770d8; line 1476 (connection #0)
* Connected to developer.api.autodesk.com (34.212.2.95) port 443 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x8000770d8; line 1532 (connection #0)
* Marked for [keep alive]: HTTP default
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => PROTOCONNECT handle 0x8000770d8; line 1547 (connection #0)
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: businessCategory=Private Organization; jurisdictionC=US; jurisdictionST=Delaware; serialNumber=2401504; C=US; ST=California; L=San Rafael; O=Autodesk, Inc.; OU=MCP-ASRD-CP; CN=developer.api.autodesk.com
*  start date: Mar 22 00:00:00 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 22 12:00:00 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "developer.api.autodesk.com" matched cert's "developer.api.autodesk.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* STATE: PROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x8000770d8; line 1566 (connection #0)
> POST /authentication/v1/authenticate HTTP/1.1
> Host: developer.api.autodesk.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Content-Length: 118
>
* upload completely sent off: 118 out of 118 bytes
* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x8000770d8; line 1621 (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => PERFORM handle 0x8000770d8; line 1743 (connection #0)
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Thu, 22 Aug 2019 05:58:08 GMT
< Content-Length: 210
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x8000770d8; line 1933 (connection #0)
* multi_done
* Connection #0 to host developer.api.autodesk.com left intact
{"developerMessage":"Requested scopes must be blank or a subset of the provided scopes.","userMessage":"","errorCode":"AUTH-004","more info":"http://developer.api.autodesk.com/documentation/v1/errors/AUTH-004"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message suggests `data:all` is not a valid scope...

See the [Resource Information](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-PUT/#resource-information) section of the endpoints you are accessing to see what scopes are required - you can specify [multiple scopes so long as they are valid](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/overview/scopes) delimited by space:

```
scope=data:read data:write bucket:read code:all
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! It worked. Whole day struggling. finally solved. I did not know I did this mistake.